# how to get length of string array

Tags: c

```
char* c[] = { "abc","abcde","abcdef","abcdefg" };
```

I used sizeof(c[0]) to get string's length but not work.
any other method to get array string length?
like abc = 3,abcde = 5.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "length of string array"? I think you mean the number of strings in the array but the reference to `sizeof(c[0])` is confusing as there is no way looking at one element can get you the full size. If it is indeed num strings in array use `sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0])`

Comment: Oh, your update implies you want `strlen(c[i])` where `i` is the index of the array entry you want the length for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any defined array, you can get the number of elements with:

```
char *c[] = { "abc", "abcde", "abcdef", "abcdefg" };
size_t c_len = sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);  // 4 elements
```

Note that `sizeof(c[0])` is the size of the array element, a pointer to `char` (`char *`) which you initialize with a pointer to a string constant that must not be changed. The type for this array should be:

```
const char *c[] = { "abc", "abcde", "abcdef", "abcdefg" };
```

There is no compile time method to get the length of these strings, you must use `strlen()`. But you can get the lengths of explicit string literals with `sizeof` this way:

```
const char *c[] = { "abc", "abcde", "abcdef", "abcdefg" };
size_t len[] = { sizeof("abc") - 1, sizeof("abcde") - 1, sizeof("abcdef") - 1, sizeof("abcdefg") - 1 };
```